# meteorjs 0.9.4 Could not resolve the specified constraints for this project: Error: tunneling socket could not be established

Tags: meteor

I was trying to run a friend's project (he did it in a mac) on my ubuntu 14.04 and I got the error specified in the title.

More detailed error: Could not resolve the specified constraints for this project:
Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=140487912306560:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:787:

JIC I have a proxy system set in my machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a proxy configuration, it seems that with a low internet connection is a very common problem.
I run export https_proxy assigning an http value and everything goes well.