# How can I fix "tunneling socket could not be established" error for all my meteor commands

Tags: meteor, meteorite

Up until a few days I could do everything in meteor but now long errors are popping up and making me nervous. I am unable to understand whats happening.

I looked up my terminal history and found the following command suspicious since there are some mentions of Cordova in the errors:

```
meteor configure-android

meteor install-sdk android
```

Here is a sample of when I run `meteor create testapp`

```
    meteor create testapp

    /home/rohan/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.klvi4f++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:206
                            throw(ex);
                                  ^
    Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=140547247318912:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:787:
        at Object.Future.wait (/home/rohan/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.klvi4f++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:326:15)
        at _.extend._createSocket (packages/ddp/stream_client_nodejs.js:265)
        at _.extend._launchConnection (packages/ddp/stream_client_nodejs.js:142)
        at new LivedataTest.ClientStream (packages/ddp/stream_client_nodejs.js:28)
        at new Connection (packages/ddp/livedata_connection.js:52)
        at Object.DDP.connect (packages/ddp/livedata_connection.js:1581)
        at new ServiceConnection (/home/rohan/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.klvi4f++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/service-connection.js:54:37)
        at Object.exports.openServiceConnection (/home/rohan/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.klvi4f++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/auth-client.js:24:10)
        at openPackageServerConnection (/home/rohan/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.klvi4f++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/package-client.js:24:21)
        at _updateServerPackageData (/home/rohan/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.klvi4f++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/package-client.js:122:14)
        at /home/rohan/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.klvi4f++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/package-client.js:100:12
        at /home/rohan/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.klvi4f++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:313:18
        at _.extend.withValue (/home/rohan/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.klvi4f++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:112:14)
        at /home/rohan/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.klvi4f++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:312:36
        at _.extend.withValue (/home/rohan/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.klvi4f++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:112:14)
        at Object.enterJob (/home/rohan/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.klvi4f++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:303:26)
        at Object.exports.updateServerPackageData (/home/rohan/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.klvi4f++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/package-client.js:99:23)
        at /home/rohan/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.klvi4f++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/catalog-remote.js:767:36
        at /home/rohan/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.klvi4f++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:313:18
        at _.extend.withValue (/home/rohan/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.klvi4f++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:112:14)
        at /home/rohan/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.klvi4f++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:312:36
        at _.extend.withValue (/home/rohan/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.klvi4f++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:112:14)
        at Object.enterJob (/home/rohan/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.klvi4f++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:303:26)
        at _.extend.refresh (/home/rohan/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.klvi4f++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/catalog-remote.js:766:18)
        at _.extend.refreshOfficialCatalog (/home/rohan/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.klvi4f++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/catalog.js:390:23)
        at Object.catalog.refreshOrWarn (/home/rohan/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.klvi4f++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/catalog.js:60:22)
        at catalog.Refresh.OnceAtStart.beforeCommand (/home/rohan/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.klvi4f++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/catalog.js:33:16)
        at /home/rohan/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.klvi4f++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/main.js:1349:32
        at /home/rohan/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.klvi4f++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:313:18
        at _.extend.withValue (/home/rohan/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.klvi4f++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:112:14)
        at /home/rohan/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.klvi4f++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:312:36
        at _.extend.withValue (/home/rohan/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.klvi4f++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:112:14)
        at Object.enterJob (/home/rohan/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.klvi4f++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:303:26)
        at /home/rohan/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.klvi4f++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/main.js:1348:20
        - - - - -

        at ClientRequest.onError (/home/rohan/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.klvi4f++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/isopacks/ddp/npm/node_modules/tunnel-agent/index.js:168:17)
        at ClientRequest.g (events.js:180:16)
        at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:95:17)
        at CleartextStream.socketErrorListener (http.js:1547:9)
        at CleartextStream.emit (events.js:95:17)
        at SecurePair.<anonymous> (tls.js:1395:15)
        at SecurePair.emit (events.js:95:17)
        at SecurePair.error (tls.js:1015:27)
        at CleartextStream.read [as _read] (tls.js:460:17)
        at CleartextStream.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:323:10)
        at EncryptedStream.write [as _write] (tls.js:366:25)
        at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:226:10)
        at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:216:5)
        at EncryptedStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:183:11)
        at write (_stream_readable.js:585:24)
        at flow (_stream_readable.js:594:7)
        at Socket.pipeOnReadable (_stream_readable.js:626:5)
        at Socket.emit (events.js:92:17)
        at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:410:10)
        at emitReadable (_stream_readable.js:406:5)
        at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:168:9)
        at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:130:10)
        at TCP.onread (net.js:528:21)
```

Here is what happens when I type `meteor update`

```
meteor create testapp

/home/rohan/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.klvi4f++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:206
                        throw(ex);
                              ^
Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=140547247318912:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:787:
    at Object.Future.wait (/home/rohan/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.klvi4f++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:326:15)
    at _.extend._createSocket (packages/ddp/stream_client_nodejs.js:265)
    at _.extend._launchConnection (packages/ddp/stream_client_nodejs.js:142)
    at new LivedataTest.ClientStream (packages/ddp/stream_client_nodejs.js:28)
    at new Connection (packages/ddp/livedata_connection.js:52)
    at Object.DDP.connect (packages/ddp/livedata_connection.js:1581)
    at new ServiceConnection (/home/rohan/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.klvi4f++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/service-connection.js:54:37)
    at Object.exports.openServiceConnection (/home/rohan/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.klvi4f++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/auth-client.js:24:10)
    at openPackageServerConnection (/home/rohan/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.klvi4f++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/package-client.js:24:21)
    at _updateServerPackageData (/home/rohan/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.klvi4f++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/package-client.js:122:14)
    at /home/rohan/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.klvi4f++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/package-client.js:100:12
    at /home/rohan/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.klvi4f++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:313:18
    at _.extend.withValue (/home/rohan/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.klvi4f++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:112:14)
    at /home/rohan/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.klvi4f++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:312:36
    at _.extend.withValue (/home/rohan/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.klvi4f++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:112:14)
    at Object.enterJob (/home/rohan/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.klvi4f++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:303:26)
    at Object.exports.updateServerPackageData (/home/rohan/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.klvi4f++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/package-client.js:99:23)
    at /home/rohan/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.klvi4f++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/catalog-remote.js:767:36
    at /home/rohan/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.klvi4f++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:313:18
    at _.extend.withValue (/home/rohan/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.klvi4f++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:112:14)
    at /home/rohan/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.klvi4f++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:312:36
    at _.extend.withValue (/home/rohan/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.klvi4f++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:112:14)
    at Object.enterJob (/home/rohan/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.klvi4f++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:303:26)
    at _.extend.refresh (/home/rohan/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.klvi4f++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/catalog-remote.js:766:18)
    at _.extend.refreshOfficialCatalog (/home/rohan/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.klvi4f++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/catalog.js:390:23)
    at Object.catalog.refreshOrWarn (/home/rohan/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.klvi4f++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/catalog.js:60:22)
    at catalog.Refresh.OnceAtStart.beforeCommand (/home/rohan/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.klvi4f++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/catalog.js:33:16)
    at /home/rohan/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.klvi4f++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/main.js:1349:32
    at /home/rohan/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.klvi4f++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:313:18
    at _.extend.withValue (/home/rohan/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.klvi4f++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:112:14)
    at /home/rohan/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.klvi4f++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:312:36
    at _.extend.withValue (/home/rohan/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.klvi4f++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:112:14)
    at Object.enterJob (/home/rohan/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.klvi4f++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:303:26)
    at /home/rohan/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.klvi4f++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/main.js:1348:20
    - - - - -

    at ClientRequest.onError (/home/rohan/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.klvi4f++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/isopacks/ddp/npm/node_modules/tunnel-agent/index.js:168:17)
    at ClientRequest.g (events.js:180:16)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at CleartextStream.socketErrorListener (http.js:1547:9)
    at CleartextStream.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at SecurePair.<anonymous> (tls.js:1395:15)
    at SecurePair.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at SecurePair.error (tls.js:1015:27)
    at CleartextStream.read [as _read] (tls.js:460:17)
    at CleartextStream.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:323:10)
    at EncryptedStream.write [as _write] (tls.js:366:25)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:226:10)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:216:5)
    at EncryptedStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:183:11)
    at write (_stream_readable.js:585:24)
    at flow (_stream_readable.js:594:7)
    at Socket.pipeOnReadable (_stream_readable.js:626:5)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:92:17)
    at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:410:10)
    at emitReadable (_stream_readable.js:406:5)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:168:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:130:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:528:21)
```

Comment: That worked! http://stackoverflow.com/a/26612808/1735250

Answer (score 0):

It looks like some proxy or something is in between you and the meteor server.

Try removing it or using a different internet connection. The issue is that the SSL handshake is failing (ps. also check that your system clock is the correct time). The correct time ensures that the SSL certificates involved are valid.

The error is in the log above with `SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol`. Typically this error would be the result of incorrectly configured code.

If you're using an unmodified version of Meteor the prime suspect would be a proxy between you and the Meteor server that also proxies SSL but is badly configured.

One thing that comes to mind is that SSL 3 has the POODLE vulnerability and your ISP/corporate proxy may have forcefully disabled it.

If you built Meteor yourself try updating your version of OpenSSL then rebuild it.

Also additional info: http://blog.techstacks.com/2010/03/3-common-causes-of-unknown-ssl-protocol-errors-with-curl.html